# Ayuda con la busqueda de duplicados

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy haciendo una hoja de calculo de google y no escuentro la solucion para marcar  que una celda esta dublicada en diferentes columnas, esto se debe berificar en todas las celdas deseadas pero no encuentro la manera, lo unico que he conseguido es que funcione por filas o columnas. El complemento "Remove duplicates no es una opción".

Ejemplo del excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Demomento esto es lo que he conseguido hacer, dejo un enlace con un ejemplo

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QPHe3B5jjjzOf395DqL9EeNfFIPT98nZuw-e4BuZHYY/edit?usp=sharing

Ahora mismo solo funcionaria por columnas, lo que yo necesito es que esto funcione en forma de cuadrante, no se si me explico bien.

---

Con una pequeña modificación he conseguido que funcione en cuadrante, ahora el problema es que esto va por dias, no se si puedo hacerlo sin tener que hacer una columna por dia.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QPHe3B5jjjzOf395DqL9EeNfFIPT98nZuw-e4BuZHYY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Si no puedes usar el addon mírate esto -> https://zapier.com/blog/remove-duplicates-google-sheets/#Formula

Comment: Mencionas que has conseguido que funcione por filas o columnas. Agrega dicha solución pues podría ser un buen punto de partida.

Comment: Solución agredada, ahora solo falta la puntillita.

Comment: @IvánMontero Las soluciones, en particular si se trata de las solución completa, deben publicarse como respuesta.